# How would you achieve the color of the pattern?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, patterns

I have the stock image of paisley floral but I am trying to achieve this color of the pattern:
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to extract the colors from the image or change the color on the pattern or something else? the question may not be very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In photoshop you need at least 2 layers for this - one for the background and one for the yellow pattern.

*The background*: 3...5 different colors are used. The background pattern is heavily blurred. There can be third layer as the second part of the background. It has blurred greenish black and maybe some yellow. It can be seen at the ends of the text MEHNDI NIGHT.

Find the colors with the color picker.

*The yellow pattern*: I believe it's white in otherwise black layer mask. The layer itself is filled with a gradient that has 2 different gold imitations. Probably bevel&emboss layer style is applied.

This is a trial of the receipe. Only random strokes, represents nothing!

[image]